# I'm looking for ad code, running on second visit

Tags: php, html, cookies

I'm working with 2 different popups for a Wordpress based site, but these two popups shouldn't open at the same time. So I need a system like this;

"X company popup code" will work when he first enters the site.
The visitors will be running the "Y company popup code" at the 2. 3. 4. ... entries.

After a 24-hour period, the cookies will be deleted and the popup code of X company  will run again at the first entry.

1. Company Popup Code (X Company)

   var username= "787";

   var tur= "4";
2. Company Popup Code (Y Company)

First I want the code 1 to work and the "2nd code" on other visits.

Unfortunately this code did not work;

```
<script language="javascript">  
    if(document.cookie.indexOf('cerrado=false')<0){
        cad=new Date()
        cad.setTime(cad.getTime() + (days*24*60*60*1000)) 
        expira="; expires=" + cad.toGMTString() 
        document.cookie = "cerrado=false" + expira 
    Here you put (X Company) the one that will be shown only once, call your popup here   

<!-- PopCent.net Popunder Code Start -->

<script>
var username= "787";
var tur= "4";
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="cdn.popcent.net/k.js"></script>

<!-- PopCent.net Popunder Code End-->
        }

    function readCookie(cookieName){
        var start = document.cookie.indexOf(cookieName);
        if (start == -1){ 
            document.cookie = "cerrado=yes; expires=" + cad.toGMTString() ;
        } else {
      here you put (Y Company) that you will show call the function or what you think
<script type='text/javascript' src='pl14936407.pvclouds.com/a0/63/c0/a063c0b5b83aefbf5e91c5af65545736.js'></script>
        }
    }
    readCookie("cerrado");
    // -->
    </script>
```

Comment: Please add some relevant code to your question, to get a better understanding of the problem.

Comment: you've stated what you want, but not what hinders you to code that!?

Comment: I'm using the popup ad code of two companies. The first company's code will work first. The user will run the second company's code on the other visit. I need php or html code for this.?!

Answer (score -1):

I hope this works for you.

```
<script language="javascript">  
    if(document.cookie.indexOf('cerrado=false')<0){
        cad=new Date()
        cad.setTime(cad.getTime() + (days*24*60*60*1000)) 
        expira="; expires=" + cad.toGMTString() 
        document.cookie = "cerrado=false" + expira 
    Here you put (X Company) the one that will be shown only once, call your popup here   
        }

    function readCookie(cookieName){
        var start = document.cookie.indexOf(cookieName);
        if (start == -1){ 
            document.cookie = "cerrado=yes; expires=" + cad.toGMTString() ;
        } else {
      here you put (Y Company) that you will show call the function or what you think
        }
    }
    readCookie("cerrado");
    // -->
    </script>
```

Comment: My ad codes are here; https://shrib.com/?v=nc#K3rYw2KbKlbUfikL4f1n                                     I couldn't add these codes to your code.